# Strings not rendered in CL-WHO template

Tags: common-lisp, cl-who

```
(require :cl-who)
(defmacro rawpage ((&rest head) &body body)
  `(cl-who:with-html-output-to-string (*standard-output* nil :prologue t)
    (:html
    (:head
      (:meta :charset "utf-8")
      ,@head)
    (:body
      ,@body))))

(defmacro str+ (&rest strs)
  `(concatenate 'string ,@strs))

(rawpage () (:div (str+ "hello," "name")))
```

This piece of codes does not output what I want.
I expected it output:

```
<html><head><meta charset='utf-8' /></head><body><div>hello,name</div></body></html>
```

But, it output:

```
<html><head><meta charset='utf-8' /></head><body><div></div></body></html>
```

Anyone could tell me why? I'm using SBCL.

Comment: A good first start is probably to do `(macroexpand-1 '(rawpage () (:div (str+ "hello," "name"))))` and see what it actually expands to. Secondly, it MAY be better to replace your `str+` macro with `(defun str+ (&rest strs) (format nil "~{~a~}" strs)` (never use a macro, where a function would do the trick).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that in CL-WHO non-constant strings should be placed inside `str` like this:

```
(defmacro rawpage ()
  (:div (str (str+ "hello," "name"))))
```